# Set an about:config setting through the url in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I want to make an easy option for turning on and off my proxy, instead of going to the settings and going through all the pages.

I looked into the about:config and I found `network.proxy.type`. It is set to `0` for no proxy and `1` for manual settings.

I tried doing `about:config?network.proxy.type=0` but that didn't work. If I get a url that works to do this, I could easily bookmark it to have buttons that turn on and off the proxy.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it could be an issue, but I assume that could be blocked easily from having websites to it. I just would like some simple way to do this.

Comment: Hopefully helpful to what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843340/firefox-proxy-settings-via-command-line

Comment: @Dave I would probably have to restart Firefox for the changes to take effect right?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know - I just found a similar post which *may* help

Comment: I found [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/toggle-proxy-51740/) add-on that does what I was looking for.

Comment: You can answer your own question :D

Answer (score 1):

[The toggle proxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/toggle-proxy-51740/) add-on for firefox allows you to turn on and off the proxy settings like what I was looking for.

Comment: I've edited to include the name of the addon. A screenshot of the screen that you use to do this would seriously improve the question. Right now its still a bit too lean on details